# Store .sav file into RDBMS including meta data

Tags: metadata, rdbms, spss

I want to know what is the best approach to store the data from .sav file into RDBMS database with out loosing any meta data model as well as actual response data.

Answer (score 0):

Note first that you can save all the metadata in a sav file where you have deleted all the data and then reapply the metadata to a new, similar sav file using APPLY DICTIONARY.

Otherwise, you would need to create tables in the database for the various attributes.  That's easy for variable labels, formats, measurement level, and missing value codes.  For value labels it would take a bit more work.

One possible approach would be to use OMS to capture the output from CODEBOOK (without any statistics) as data files and then export those files to the database.